# Rewrite procedure to search for open excel workbook

Tags: excel, visual-studio

I wrote the procedure below to check for an open instance of Excel and then check to see if a particular workbook was opened, if the workbook is opened, then go to the selected sheet.

The procedure works OK, but I am not particularly happy with the way I wrote it. For example, on the following lines, the procedure checks if the workbook is opened, if not, it goes out to the path and opens it by using the `Catch` .

```
  Dim xlWBName As String = "2011.1004.Compensation Template"
  Dim xlBookPath As String = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())

    xlApp.Visible = True

    Try

        'get the opened workbook

        xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks(xlWBName & ".xlsx")

    Catch ex As Exception

        'open it
        xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlBookPath & "\" & xlWBName & ".xlsx")

    End Try
```

I don't want to use the `Catch` as the way to open my workbook if it is not already opened. I rather use it for a true exception such as the workbook not being in the directory. My question is, how can re-write this procedure to better do what I want. Here is my entire procedure:

Public Sub GoToSheets(sheetName As String)

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.AppStarting

frmPleaseWait.Show()

Try
    'get an existing excel.application object
    xlApp = CType(GetObject(, "Excel.Application"), Application)

Catch ex As Exception
    'no existing excel.application object - create a new one

    xlApp = New Excel.Application

End Try

Dim xlWBName As String = "2011.1004.Compensation Template"
Dim xlBookPath As String = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())

xlApp.Visible = True

Try

    'get the opened workbook

    xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks(xlWBName & ".xlsx")

Catch ex As Exception

    'open it
    xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlBookPath & "\" & xlWBName & ".xlsx")

End Try

Try

    xlSheet = CType(CType(xlBook.Sheets(sheetName), Excel.Worksheet), Excel.Worksheet)

    xlSheet.Activate()
    frmPleaseWait.Close()

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp)

    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

    'Show curser waiting
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor

Catch ex As Exception

    'Catch any other exceptions here
    MessageBox.Show("An exception occurred while processing the file" & vbNewLine & ex.GetType.ToString, "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

End Try
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you're getting trying to find an instance of Excel is probably because of the `CType` failing and throwing an `InvalidCastException`. You can probably avoid that by avoiding the cast (initially):

```
Dim xlObject As Object

Try
    'get an existing excel.application object
    xlObject = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Catch ex As Exception
    ' Some other exception now

End Try

If Not xlObject Is Nothing Then ' Found something, make the cast
    xlApp = CType(xlObject, Application)
Else ' Did not find anything, create new instance
    xlApp = New Excel.Application
End If
```

And to check if the Workbook exists, just loop through them and check their names:

```
Dim isWbOpen As Boolean
For i As Integer = 0 To xlApp.Workbooks.Count - 1
    If xlApp.Workbooks(i).Name = xlWBName Then
        isWbOpen = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If isWbOpen Then
    xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks(xlWBName & ".xlsx")
Else
    xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlBookPath & "\" & xlWBName & ".xlsx")
End If
```

Comment: Thank you, not only did it solve my problem, it actually works faster as well.